# Painting/staining around screen

Tags: wood, painting, screens

Had new PT screened-in porch installed ~ 1 month ago. Screened doors need sealing now, as they swell when get wet. What is best way to paint around screen w/o getting paint on screen? Painter’s tape will not stick to screen. I’ve been using a putty knife & a straight edge to paint slats in doors. Very frustrating & time consuming! Any advice/ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quality DIY work is always time comsuming. Seeing great results should minimize the frustration.  You can always hire a pro and then be frustrated when paying the bill.  Masking tape will stick to screens.

Comment: Use more sticky tape like regular beige masking tape.  Also make sure you use quality painter's tape, as lots of really bad blue tape is out there. Nobody does adhesives like 3M.  Make sure to dry the door as much as possible - wood doesn't dry over days, it dries over months. I'd bring it inside and store it for a few weeks at least to dry it out for paint.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably 10-20 years experience as a painter. Those folks don't use masking tape much.

The best way for normal folks is to learn what you can from how people like that do it, take your time, and stop before you get too frustrated, coming back to it later.

One of the things I've learned (and I'm no pro) is that it's a bad to paint out of a can for multiple reasons, one of which is that you can't easily and consistently get rid of excess paint on the brush or roller so you have paint in it, but you don't drip all over things. There are other reasons to use a paint tray even for small jobs, but that's a big one.

Another is that sometimes you really do need to buy a decent brush for good results, as the low end of cheap brushes is pretty awful. You don't need the most expensive brush on the planet, but there comes a point in the race to the bottom where the cheapness of the brush gets expensive in the negative effects on being able to paint well with it. Having bought one, clean it after use religiously (though, for water-based paint,  plastic wrap and the refrigerator or an ice chest can be an option if you'll be back to the job soon, after you're less frustrated.) You can get decades of use from a good brush, if you take care of it.